# How to structure my HTTP Requests in React without having to rewrite everything?

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I am new to react, I come from a background in angular.

I have an API running on localhost, and wrote a Login page:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./login.css";

const Login = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleLogin = (e) => 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var body = {
            username: username,
            password: password
        }
        
        var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};

        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
        };

        try {
            fetch("http://localhost:5000/API/user/Authenticate", requestOptions)
                .then((response) => 
                {
                    if(!response.ok)
                    {
                        return Promise.reject(response);
                    }               
                    else 
                    {
                        return response.json();
                    }
                })
                .then((data) => 
                {
                    localStorage.setItem("token", "Bearer " + data.token);
                    navigate('/', {replace: true});
                })
                .catch((response) => 
                {
                    if(response.status === 401)
                    {
                        setError("Invalid username and password combination");
                    }
                });
        }
        catch (err)
        {
            setError(err);
        }
    }

    return (
        <section className="h-100">
            <header className="container h-100 w-100">
                <div className="d-flex align-items-center flex-column justify-content-center h-100 w-100">
                    <div className="logo">
                        <span className="big">IMS</span>
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                        <span className="small">solutions</span>
                    </div>
                    <form style={{ width: "30%" }} className="d-flex flex-column" onSubmit={handleLogin}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
                            <input className="form-control" value={username} onChange={(e) => {setUsername(e.target.value)} } type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username . . ." />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
                            <input className="form-control" value={password} onChange={(e) => {setPassword(e.target.value)} } type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password . . ." />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                            <span>{error}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                            <input type="submit" value="login" className="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </header>
        </section>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

The code works fine, but i am wondering how i can extract my post request code to a seperate service that i can call like this:

```
service.post(url, headers, body);
```

or similarly. I can easily do that in angular, but i tried to do so with react and cannot figure out how to structure a hook.

I tried to create a hook called getPost in a different file and run it through like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useGet = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  var abort = new AbortController();

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
          fetch(url, { signal: abort })
            .then((response) => {
                  if (!response.ok)
                  {
                    throw Error("Unable to complete request");
                  }
            })
            .then((data) => 
            {
                  setData(data);
            });
        return abort.abort();
    }
    catch (err) 
    {
      setError(err);
    }
  }, []);

  return {data, error};
};

const usePost = (url, {headers = null, body = null}) => {

    const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    var abort = new AbortController();
    var defaultHeaders = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
    const finalHeaders = { ...defaultHeaders, ...headers };
    
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: finalHeaders,
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        signal: abort
    };

    try {
        fetch(url, requestOptions)
            .then((response) => 
            {
                if(!response.ok)
                {
                    throw Error("Unable to complete request");
                }                
                else 
                {
                    response.json();
                    setStatus(response.ok);
                }
            });
        return abort.abort();
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        setError(err);
    }
    return {status, error};
}

export { useGet, usePost };
```

The useGet function works as expected. But i need usePost to run on submit.

The result was Error: Invalid hook call.

So I am just wondering how does one structure GET, POST, DELETE, and UPDATE requests without having to rewrite the whole request ?

Comment: Please, look into useSWR or react-query. I know people tend to like to write their own code over use libraries, but these will solve every problem you’ve ever hard or will ever have with async/server side state

Comment: I will look into them, thank you. Do you have a bias towards one of those ? Maybe one works better than others ?

Comment: @Adam from what i can tell with react-query they create a hook that returns a function, which you then run in the handleSubmit function, thats easier than i thought to recreate, but react-querys caching functionality is awesome, definitely going to mess with it. thank you